# Sending documents as e-mail attachments

Tags: 2010, document-library, ecb-menu

We have document library where we store various types of documents (word, ppt, infopath templates etc..)

The requirement is to send them as e-mail attachments directly from SharePoint Document Library by usage of right click.

Please provide some guidance on steps required to achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

You already have OOTB functionality `Send to > E-Mail`

[image]

IMO sending files from a Document Library by e-mail defeats the whole idea of SharePoint. Instead of sending an e-mail you should send links and grant some access (permission level) on document to mail recipients.

However it is possible to build additional context item with custom action. You need to have some coding skills and basic knowledge of SharePoint development. Here is example on how to do it in 2007 version:

- [Send a SharePoint document library file as email](http://blog.furuknap.net/send-a-sharepoint-document-library-file-as-email)

This example can be easily converted to 2010 platform.

Comment: OOTB == Out Of The Box?

Comment: Yes. OOTB == Out Of The Box

Answer (score 1):

I use the Outlook Connector from CodePlex to browse my SharePoint libraries in Outlook and attach documents, etc. http://spoutlookconnector.codeplex.com/

Comment: +1 it looks nice and handy (not something I would use but still good)